# I Need to Use toggle option in datatable using Twitter Bootstrap icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have done a datatable which will get data from web service and fill the data itself. I have introduced an action button on a column in the datatable, which has `<i class="icon-lock">`. Now when i click this icon, it should toggle and changed into `<i class="icon-unlock">`

```
$('#test').dataTable({
            "aaData": realdata,
            "aoColumns": [// "bVisible": false (To disable
        { "sTitle": "First Name", "mData": "FirstName", "sClass": "header2" },
        { "sTitle": "Last Name", "mData": "LastName", "sClass": "header2" },
        { "sTitle": "Email ID", "mData": "Email", "sClass": "header2" },
        { "sTitle": "Role", "mData": "Role", "sClass": "header2" },

                  {
                      "sTitle": "Action", "fnRender": function (oObj) {

                          if (oObj.aData["IsActive"] == "Y")
                              ActionHtml += "<a href='#' class='bs-tooltip Enable' title='' data-original-title='Search'><i class='icon-lock' onclick='EnableUser();'/></i></a>&nbsp|&nbsp";
                          else
                              ActionHtml += "<a href='#' class='bs-tooltip Enable' title='' data-original-title='Search'><i class='icon-unlock' onclick='EnableUser();'/></i></a>&nbsp|&nbsp";

                          return ActionHtml + '</span>';
                      }


                  }
            ]
        });

    });
function EnableUser() {
        $('.icon-lock').toggleClass('icon-unlock');
    }
```

Now when click the icon, i can get the toggle functionality with icon changing from **icon-lock** to **icon-unlock**.. But it is applied to all icon in all the rows in that column. I want it to apply only one row at a time.

Comment: use $(this) instead of select all the class $('.icon-lock')

Comment: It seems not working after replaced like this $(this).toggleClass('icon-unlock');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the onclick from the HTML and bind the click in JS like this

```
$(document).on('click','.Enable', function(){  
    $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-lock glyphicon-unlock');  // using glyphicon as class here for the demo
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w3y36yq/)

Your code wasn't working because you are not passing `this` to `onclick=EnableUser()`. You can then use `this` and toggle the classes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.icon-lock, .icon-unlock').on('click',function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('icon-lock').toggleClass('icon-unlock');
       });
    });
```

see demo [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f1jesggL/)